# how to append a string at the end of a line but also before some n characters

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing

how to add some string at the end of the line in  a file : But also before 3 charcters .

I tried but ended up by appending at the last of the string .can anyone help me pls

Example :
I/P:

```
file1.txt
```

content :

```
a
bbbb
vvvvv
cccccc
dd
rules('example here i dont need to get added')
rules('test', [abc,bcd]).
```

I tried using

```
sed -i '/rules/ s/$/ ***/' file1.txt
```

O/P:

```
rules('test',[abc,bcd]). ***
```

But preffered o/p:

```
rules('test',[abc,bcd,***]).
```

I have two lines that matches rules but i need to get occured for the 2nd line 
i tried this

```
sed '/rules/ s/\(...\)$/ ,***\1/'
```

but it is not working

Comment: Try `sed '/rules/ s/\(...\)$/,***\1/' `

Comment: yes it is working but what if i have two lines that matches same rules  but i need this to append for 2nd line

Comment: Hi! You also want to remove the `'.*'`?

Comment: sry it was a typo @FrancescoLucianò : no need to take care of '.*'

Comment: Please, modify your question so the input and the output are consistent (add `'.*'` to the output or remove it from the input)

Comment: @FrancescoLucianò done ! formatted correctly ... sed '/rules/ s/\(...\)$/,***\1/2'   is not working ... can u help me

Comment: Why you say is not working? What output do you get? What did you expect? You can add this try to your question. How can we understand which line you want to modify?

Comment: @yugandhar. Of course my answer is now incorrect! You changed the requirements and the sample file. For the new sample file and requirements, try `sed '/rules/ s/\(]).\)$/,***\1/'`

Answer (score 2):

try

```
'/rules/ s/\(\]..\)$/,***\1/'
```

as replace pattern.

where

- `\(` ... `\)` "grep" the pattern in `\1`
- `\]..` pattern is closing bracket (not sure it need escaping) and any two char
- `,***\1` add stars and comma before.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
sed -E '/rules/ s/(]\)\.)$/,***\1/' file1.txt
```

Input:

```
a
bbbb
vvvvv
cccccc
dd
rules('example here i dont need to get added')
rules('test', [abc,bcd]).
```

Output:

```
a
bbbb
vvvvv
cccccc
dd
rules('example here i dont need to get added')
rules('test', [abc,bcd,***]).
```

In this way, you get the output on stdout. If you want to modify the file, add the `-i` option:

```
sed -i -E '/rules/ s/(]\)\.)$/,***\1/' file1.txt
```